# Haskell & The Implementation of Functional Languages book

Tags: haskell

I'm having trouble executing the chapters of the book *Implementing Functional Languages: a tutorial* by Simon L Peyton Jones and David R Lester.

I'm using ghc on OSX and I'm using make to generate the input, e.g. "make language.lhs" and "make utils.lhs".

```
peano:pj-lester-book bwat$ make utils.lhs
cat utils.src | ./make-version 1 G >utils.lhs
peano:pj-lester-book bwat$ make language.lhs
make: *** No rule to make target `language-tutor.src', needed by `language.lhs'.    Stop.
peano:pj-lester-book bwat$ touch language-tutor.src
peano:pj-lester-book bwat$ make language.lhs
cat language.src language-tutor.src | ./make-version 3 G > language.lhs
peano:pj-lester-book bwat$ ghci
GHCi, version 7.8.4: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude> :load language
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( language.lhs, interpreted )

language.lhs:708:23:
    Not in scope: ‘foldll’
    Perhaps you meant one of these:
      ‘foldl1’ (imported from Prelude), ‘foldl’ (imported from Prelude),
      ‘foldr’ (imported from Prelude)

[Other similar errors deleted to save space]
```

Has anybody gone through this book with ghc?

Comment: Don't ask questions like "Has anybody gone through this book with ghc?"  The answer is almost certainly yes.  Ask a different, more specific question, and *ask it on Stack Overflow.*

Comment: You really need to state whether that error message is relevant or not – are you sure you meant `foldll` with a lower-case L at the end rather than `foldl1` with the trailing number one? If so, where did you define that function, and how did you load that code? If not, simply fix your mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at Appendix A.5, which defines a number of functions to avoid compatibility problems with changing versions.  From that appendix:

[image: screenshot from appendix]

Also, that book was written with examples in Miranda, not Haskell.  You might find several cases with small incompatibilities where you need a deeper understanding than just copying and pasting.